# How can I get the number of times my function in functions.php has echo?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am new to WordPress, I was trying to display on my front page a specific number of posts that I have and then add a "load more articles" button. When clicking on the button it will load another three posts and if there are more posts left it will appear again, otherwise it will not be displayed.

The problem I am currently having is that I can't count the times my function (*function in functions.php that displays the posts, it has `get_posts();` and an echo at the end*) is echoing (*how many posts is it going to show*).

I tried declaring a global variable outside the function used to count to assign its value to it, but it didn't work, this is what I did:

```
global $counter;

function post () {
   $posts = get_posts();
   $counter = count( get_posts() );

   foreach($posts  as $post ) {
      $output .= '<div>
                    <h2>'. $post-> get_title() .'</h2>
                 </div>';
   }

echo $output;

}
```

Anyone have an idea of how else I can get the number of posts that I am getting from the `get_posts();`?

Comment: alternatively search for local storage of browser or cookie or session.

Answer (score 0):

you can return with multi data like this

```
function post(){
  $posts = get_posts();
  $output = '';
  foreach($posts  as $post )
    $output .= '<div><h2>'. $post->get_title() .'</h2></div>';
  return ['counter'=>count($posts) , 'posts'=>$output]
}
$posts=post();
echo $posts['counter'];
echo $posts['posts'];
```

Comment: Thank you! But I went with another direction, I assigned an id to each item and used the `$('.class_name_tey_all_share').last()[0].id ` to get to the last element